# How to find valid FQDN value for my ambari agent

Tags: docker-compose, ambari, fqdn

I am using this project : https://github.com/adoroszlai/ambari-runtime-compose.git to run ambari on my local system

The docker compose includes one server and one agent.

After running the containers, there are few installation steps :

[image]

I am struggling with what could be the valid FQDN name

I tried `hostname`, `hostname -f`, `hostname --fqdn` inside my agent container.
All these 3 values are returing the container id.
So, I tried container id as well but no luck.

Should I add a new entry in the ambari agent's /etc/hosts, not sure what is the correct approach.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

In Compose, you'd use `extra_hosts`, not modify `/etc/hosts` directly.

Using the container ID (or the IP address shown from `docker inspect`) is the more appropriate solution, however. Otherwise you would just use the container service name in the bridge network.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Worth pointing out that Ambari Agent-Server communication requires SSH, and having an SSH-server and multiple other processes (that Ambari would install) within containers is a Docker anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add your hosts in /etc/hosts as fqdn (Fully Qualified Domain Name) such as "node1.domain.com" and put the full list of all node fqdn's on every node.